# RMarkdown: Floating TOC AND TOC at the start of the report

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I want to have both: a floating TOC and a TOC at the start of the report (in Rmarkdown). I think it's only possible to have **one.**

[image: What I want to have]

Here, I have *manually* added a TOC.

```
---
title: "Report"
author: "Anon"
date: '2022-07-20'
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_depth: 2
    collapsed: true
    smooth_scroll: true
---

## Table of Contents 

- R Markdown
- Including Plots



## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:



## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
```

I followed this question but I can either have a floating TOC OR a TOC at the beginning. I want both. It's one of the requirement by a client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The template that `html_document` uses can't do this, but it's easy to edit it to allow for both.

1. To find the default template, use

   ```
   system.file("rmd/h/default.html", package = "rmarkdown")
   ```
2. Get a copy of that file in the editor, and find these lines:

```
$if(toc_float)$
$else$
$if(toc)$
<div id="$idprefix$TOC">
$if(toc-title)$
<h2 id="$idprefix$toc-title">$toc-title$</h2>
$endif$
$toc$
</div>
$endif$
$endif$
```

Change them to

```
$if(toc)$
<div id="$idprefix$TOC">
$if(toc-title)$
<h2 id="$idprefix$toc-title">$toc-title$</h2>
$endif$
$toc$
</div>
$endif$
```

(i.e. make the block unconditional, instead of conditioning on not having `toc_float` set.)  Save this file, e.g. to "toc2.html".

3. In the YAML for your document, add the option to specify this template, i.e. it should be

```
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_depth: 2
    collapsed: true
    smooth_scroll: true
    template: toc2.html
```

That should do it!